# Counting string occurrences in second column which corresponds to first columns of a file

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have this Input text file:

```
CD196_RS15035       normal alleles
CD196_RS15035       normal alleles
CD196_RS15035       truncation in the allele
CD196_RS15035       truncation in the allele
CD196_RS15035       no stop for allele
CD196_RS15035       no stop for allele
CD196_RS16835       normal alleles
CD196_RS16835       truncation in the allele
CD196_RS16835       no stop for allele
CD196_RS16835       no stop for allele
```

I want to count the number of times each string occurs in the second column which corresponds to the first column.

I want Output text file like this:

```
CD196_RS15035  normal alleles  2    truncation in the allele   2    no stop for allele  2
 
CD196_RS16835  normal alleles  1    truncation in the allele   1    no stop for allele  2
```

Any tip would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`'s multidimensional array:

```
awk -F'[ ]{2,}'
  '{ a[$1][$2]+=1 }
   END{ 
       for (i in a) { 
           printf("%s ", i);
           for (j in a[i]) printf("%s %d ", j, a[i][j]); 
           print "";  
       }
   }'
  test.txt
```

---

```
CD196_RS15035 normal alleles 2 no stop for allele 2 truncation in the allele 2 
CD196_RS16835 normal alleles 1 no stop for allele 2 truncation in the allele 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential option could be to 'build up' each line by looping through the variables, e.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

{
    a[$1 FS $2]++
    b[$1]
    c[$2]
}

END {
    for (i in b) {
        output = i
        for (j in c) {
            output = output FS j FS a[i FS j]
        }
        print output
    }
}' file.txt
CD196_RS15035   normal alleles  2   no stop for allele  2   truncation in the allele    2
CD196_RS16835   normal alleles  1   no stop for allele  2   truncation in the allele    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are tab-delimited, you could this with `datamash`:

```
datamash groupby 1,2 count 2  |

# Join 2nd column and its count
sed 's/\t/ /2'                |

# Collapse on the 1st column
datamash groupby 1 collapse 2
```

Output:

```
CD196_RS15035   normal alleles 2,truncation in the allele 2,no stop for allele 2
CD196_RS16835   normal alleles 1,truncation in the allele 1,no stop for allele 2
```